# Why is negative heat capacity for black holes considered problematic?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, black-holes, qft-in-curved-spacetime, black-hole-thermodynamics

Negative heat capacity of black holes (semiclassical treatment, so not entirely classical) is considered mysterious/problematic. Why is this so? What is so wrong about negative heat capacity? Does negative heat capacity go in conflict with classical general relativity?

Comment: The heat capacity is essentially (proportional) to the second derivative of the free energy with respect to temperature. The free energy is minimal at equilibrium so the second derivative must be positive. A negative value shows an instability.

Comment: Added. So negative heat capacity is in conflict with equilibrium statistical mechanics.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/194347/50583 Also, please be more specific what you mean by "problematic" - what source has given you this impression without elaborating on it?